# How to compare a session's value? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cannot find the way of how to compare a session's value.

Query for the database:

```
 conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT id_cliente,alias,area FROM tbleuser WHERE usuario=@username AND pass=@thepassword",conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",user.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thepassword", pas.Text);
        SqlDataReader r = comando.ExecuteReader();


        while(r.Read())
        {

            Session["UsuarioId"] = r["id_cliente"].ToString();
            Session["AreaUsuario"] = r["area"].ToString();
            Session["AliasUsuario"] = r["alias"].ToString();
           checkUser();
        }
```

The checkUser method should compare what kind of user is with the Alias field and here are the opcions i have used.

## 1

```
if(Session["AliasUsuario"].ToString() == "Doctors")
{
//not working
}
```

## 2

```
if(Convert.ToString(Session["AliasUsuario"]) == "Doctors")
{
//not working
}
```

## 3

```
if(Convert.ToString(Session["AliasUsuario"]).Equals("Doctors"))
{
//not working
}
```

## 4

```
if(Session["AliasUsuario"].ToString().Equals("Doctors"))
{
//not working
}
```

Any suggestions? I need to know what kind of user is login in before continue.
Thanks

Comment: not working is a bit vague, are you running into an error? is the session variable even set?

Comment: Are you in IHttpHandler context?

Comment: of course it had been set

Comment: do u get any error back? did u check if `Session["user"]` is null or not? try this :`"Doctors".Equals((String)Sesssion["user"])`

Comment: @EinerSantanaR then just maybe you could share what the error is?!

Comment: @bas done, there is the whole code.

Comment: @DarthVader i post the value of the user session in a label and it throws the correct value

Comment: Check again, the post have been edited

Comment: @EinerSantanaR can you show a piece of code how you set label text from a session?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx):

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Boolean
>   **true** if there are more rows; otherwise **false**.

Now, if your command returns more than one row then values other than expected might be set. That's something to be aware of.

From your comments it looks like you might be trying to read session variable before it was set.

Also it is very possible that value `Doctors` has slipped into database with white-space character(s) (`\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`, `space`) which are often not visible in database tools like SQL Server management studio. To check if that's the case you might use something like this:

```
if(Session["AliasUsuario"] != null)
{
    if (Session["AliasUsuario"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("doctors"))
    {
        // that's the case
    }
}
```

Also try checking what's the value of `Session["AliasUsuario"]` right after a `while` loop. A simple breakpoint could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If `SqlDataReader r = comando.ExecuteReader();` does not return any rows you set nothing to session and therefore you cannot read anything
I would go with something like:

```
if (r.HasRows)
{
    while(r.Read())
    {
        Session["UsuarioId"] = r["id_cliente"].ToString();
        Session["AreaUsuario"] = r["area"].ToString();
        Session["AliasUsuario"] = r["alias"].ToString();
        checkUser();
    }   
}
else
{
        Session["UsuarioId"] = "none";
        Session["AreaUsuario"] = "none";
        Session["AliasUsuario"] = "none";
}
```

Comment: It does return rows and i can posted in a label which means that the session it set.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like might be overlooking a simple mistake: String comparisson is case sensitive (unless you specify otherwise).

Also maybe you're comparing singular and plural (`Doctor` vs `Doctors`)?

Third, the keys in your configuration file will also be case sensitive. So `AliasUsuario` is not the same as `Aliasusuario`.

Comment: where the the **Aliasusuario** key that i cant see it?

Comment: I mean to say, make sure you check if your spelling is exactly the same on setting the configuration key (through code or through a settings file) and on reading the value.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the the exact same key the whole day and i still not knowing why it doesnt compare the session's value